# INSERT INTO table SELECT not giving correct last_id

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables with similar columns in MYSQL. I am copying data from one to another with `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1=smth`. I have different columns as autoincrement and KEY in tables. When I use `mysqli_insert_id` i get the first one rather then last one inserted. Is there any way to get the last one?

Thanks

Comment: This is impossible to answer if you don't share anything about your database structure, sample data and PHP code. At first sight, you shouldn't get any AUTO_INCREMENT at all since you don't appear to leave any column blank but of course it's all a guess.

Comment: mysqli_insert_id() will only ever give you ONE id value anyways. it's not possible to get the ids from a multi-record insert. if you need the ids, then do single/individual inserts and last_insert_id() every single one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inherit ordering of data in a relational database. You have to specify which field it is that you wish to order by like:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1=smth 
ORDER BY <field to sort by here> 
LIMIT 1;
```

Relying on the order a record is written to a table is a very bad idea. If you have an auto-numbered `id` on `table1` then just use `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` to sort the result set by ID in descending order and pick the last one.

---

Updated to address OP's question about `mysqli_insert_id`

According to the Mysql reference the function called here is `last_insert_id()` where it states:

> Important If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted
>   row only. The reason for this is to make it possible to reproduce
>   easily the same INSERT statement against some other server.

Unfortunately, you'll have to do a second query to get the true "Last inserted id". Your best bet might be to run a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE column1=smth;` and then use that `count(*)` return to add to the `mysqli_insert_id` value. That's not great, but if you have high volume where this one function is getting hit a lot, this is probably the safest route.

The less safe route would be `SELECT max(id) FROM table2` or `SELECT max(id) FROM table2 Where column1=smth`. But... again, depending on your keys and the number of times this insert is getting hit, this might be risky.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not very clear. The problem is that the SELECT bit returns a few records, and when those records are added into table2, mysqli_insert_id returns first autoicremented id. So if, lets say, it selects 3 records from table1, inserts them into table2 and create for them IDs 4,5,6 - mysqli_insert_id will return 4, not 6.

Comment: Gotcha! I always sink to the lowest common denominator on here. I've answered enough questions where someone was relying on the order of records in InnoDB that I just assume that's what's meant. I've done my best to answer your question specifically about `mysql_insert_id()`